# Nomad : Error getting job struct: Error parsing job file

Tags: nomad

I'm trying to run the command on the Nomad file:

```
nomad job run -address="http://10.10.5.11:4646" file.hcl
```

And I get an error:

```
Error getting job struct: Error parsing job file from file.hcl: error parsing 'job': 3 errors occurred:
    * group: 'prometheus' -> invalid key: network
    * group: 'prometheus' -> invalid key: volume
    * group: 'prometheus' -> invalid key: service
```

Usually there is such an error if a non-.hcl file is parsed, but in this case everything is correct.
Checked the dependencies of the Nomad package, granted the rights to execute the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by installing the latest version of Nomad (v1.5.5) according to the instructions: https://www.hashicorp.com/official-packaging-guide
(You may need to use a VPN during installation if you do not have access to the https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com/ repository)